# How can I rollback a MySql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, rollback

I'm developing a MySql transaction where I call a Stored Procedure function (INSERT statement), like:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT nameOffunction(param1, param2, ...) AS result;
ROLLBACK;
```

but when I rollback the transaction (in backend) it does not work as I expected. I saw that you can start transaction in the function with

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
   BEGIN
ROLLBACK; 
   END;
```

But at function's leven I can not perform the callback.

Any ideas or better practices?

Comment: 'Restrictions for Stored Functions' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions 'Statements that perform explicit or implicit commit or rollback. ' so no can do.. Try explaining what you are trying to do rather than your approach. Why for example would you want to wrap a select in a transaction?

Comment: @P.Salmon In my backend I start transaction, with INSERT, SELECTS, and this function that insert and get the code of the inserted entity. After the function, in backend, I detect an error, and invoke a rollback. All my other statements rollbacks correcty, but my stored function don't rollback.

Comment: As the docs say you cannot rollback in a function..Out of interest please publish your function code

Comment: There is nothing transactional in `SELECT`.  Is there an `INSERT` (or other DML) hiding somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It was because I had MyISam engine at the table where I was working. I changed into InnoDB and it works correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).